# Lisp Macro Multiple Tasks

Tags: if-statement, macros, lisp, common-lisp

I have a question about lisp macros. I want to check a condition and, if it's true, to run a few things, not only one. The same for the false way. Can anybody please help??

```
(defmacro test (condition (&rest then) (&rest else))
  `(if ,condition (progn ,@then) (progn ,@else)))

(test (= 4 3)
      (print "YES") (print "TRUE")
      (print "NO") (print "FALSE"))
```

Comment: I've rolled back the question because the accepted answer is not related to the changes you made to the question. You should ask a new question if the requirements are different.

Comment: Note that in a nested macro parameter list, `(&rest x)` means the same thing as just `x`. Your macro can be written as `(defmacro test (condition then-forms else-forms) \`(if ,condition (progn ,@then-forms) (progn ,@else-forms)))`.   From that it should be obvious that it requires exactly three arguments, whereas you're passing it five in the test case.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to test macros is to use [`macroexpand`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm).

Your test case misses parens (lisp reader does not care about whitespace, such as line breaks and indentation):

```lisp
(macroexpand '(test (= 4 3)
                    (print "YES") (print "TRUE")
                    (print "NO") (print "FALSE")))
  Error while parsing arguments to DEFMACRO TEST:
    too many elements in
      ((= 4 3) (PRINT "YES") (PRINT "TRUE") (PRINT "NO") (PRINT "FALSE"))
    to satisfy lambda list
      (CONDITION (&REST THEN) (&REST ELSE)):
    exactly 3 expected, but got 5
```

while

```lisp
(macroexpand '(test (= 4 3)
                    ((print "YES") (print "TRUE"))
                    ((print "NO") (print "FALSE"))))
(IF (= 4 3)
    (PROGN (PRINT "YES") (PRINT "TRUE"))
    (PROGN (PRINT "NO") (PRINT "FALSE")))
```

Please note that CL has [`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm)
which is usually used when one needs multiple forms in
[`if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) clauses.